# accordion within accordion collapses parent accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm using jqueryui's accordion control. I'm required to set up a navigation that involves accordions within accordions. It *looks* like it builds all the accordions okay. I expand the first one and see the second one. When I expand the second one, I see it expand, but then its parent accordion rolls up and hides the child accordion I just expanded.

This codepen shows my problem: http://codepen.io/chodenode/pen/Evnsz

Many thanks for any help:

My HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<body>
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li class="parent-li">
            <span class="topic"><a href="">Cardiac</a></span>
            <span class="header"></span>
            <ul>
                <li class="parent-li">
                    <span class="topic">Coronary Atherosclerosis</span>
                    <span class="header"></span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Clinical Outcome Profile</a>
                            <span class="header"></span>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Coronary Atherosclerosis Per 1000 ACA</li>
                                <li>Coronary Atherosclerosis Comorbidity</li>
                                <li>Coronary Atherosclerosis % with PTCA</li>
                                <li>Coronary Atherosclerosis Mortality Rate</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="parent" href="">MS-DRG Care Management Profile</a>
                            <span class="header"></span>
                            <ul>
                                <li>MS-DRG 286 Circulatory disorders except AMI w card cath w MCC</li>
                                <li>MS-DRG 302 Atherosclerosis w MCC</li>
                                <li>MS-DRG 303 Atherosclerosis w/o MCC</li>
                                <li>MS-DRG 304 Hypertension w MCC</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="parent-li">
                    <span class="topic">Chest Pain</span>
                </li>
                <li class="parent-li">
                    <span class="topic">Angina</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent-li">
            <span class="topic">Vascular</span>
            <span class="header"></span>
            <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent-li">
            <span class="topic">Respiratory</span>
            <span class="header"></span>
            <ul></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation').accordion({
        header: '.header',
        event: 'click',
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: 'content',
        active: false,
        fillSpace: true,
    });

    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/14616985/1847695 any help.

It looks like the each nested accordian is within a `<div>` tag, then the javascript becomes:

```
$("div.accordian").accordion({ <options> });
```

This was about the only option I haven't yet tried on your codepen sample.

Comment: I just tried putting all my ul's into a div and that didn't seem to help. They still roll up when I click one of the lower level accordions. The problem seems to revolve around using the header property. Clicking something with the same properties as what's in header triggers the collapse event, even though it's further down. I tried the above guy's solution with using different id's, but also using different classes for the header property and it's separating them out.

Comment: I can make subaccordians similar to another codepen example you linked to yesterday, but playing in jsFiddle I can't generate anything like what you require, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a seperate `id` and `header` for the sub-accordion.  by using the same `id` and `header` jQuery is collapsing everything at the same time.

The following should get you on the right track... I just copied your original accordion declaration and updated it with a `sub_` prefix

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#navigation').accordion({
    header: '.header',
    event: 'click',
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: 'content',
    active: false,
    fillSpace: true,
});
$('#sub_navigation').accordion({
    header: '.sub_header',
    event: 'click',
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: 'content',
    active: false,
    fillSpace: true,
});
```

Then update your html to reflect the script changes:

```
<body>
<ul id="navigation">
    <li class="parent-li">
        <span class="topic"><a href="">Cardiac</a></span>
        <span class="header"></span>
        <ul>
            <li id="sub_navigation" class="parent-li">
                <span class="topic">Coronary Atherosclerosis</span>
                <span class="sub_header"></span>
```