# Angular UI accordion within an accordion

Tags: angularjs, accordion

Is there a way in Angular UI to have an accordion within an accordion?  I want the top level list to all be closed until one item is selected, and then to accordion open to show another accordion list that will also open and close.

With my current implementation, when I select the inner list item both accordions are triggered, leaving the inner one closed.  Aren't they in their own $scopes?

This question is similar, but for jQuery: [accordion within accordion collapses parent accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15094108/584846)

```
<accordion>
  <accordion-group ng-repeat="folder in folders | orderBy:'name' " ng-click="select_folder(folder)">
    <accordion-heading>
      {{ folder.name }}
    </accordion-heading>
    <accordion>
      <accordion-group ng-repeat="file in folder.files">
        <accordion-heading>
          {{ file.name }}
        </accordion-heading>
        {{ file.info }}
      </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Comment: this may sound stupid, but try adding `ng-if="true"` to the inner `accordion-group`. `ng-if` will force a new isolated scope (which is a hacky side-effect). This is not intended as a solution, but if it works it's a clue as to the problem and then possibly a good solution.

Comment: Another option that may be ok for you but is not exactly what you're asking for is to set `close-others` on each accordion to false.

Comment: Update: I'm pretty sure this is not related to scopes at all. Accordions store their array of accordion groups in a local variable declared inside AccordionController.

Comment: Then it sounds like it's possible to have nested accordion lists.

Comment: Seems like it should be possible. I don't know why it isn't working. I looked through the accordion code on github and nothing stood out as a clear explanation. If you create a Plunkr I'll look into it some more. I'm curious too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem.  There should not be an `ng-click` attribute on the `<accordion-group>` tag.  By moving that down to the `<accordion-heading>` tag, the nested accordions work correctly.  This is also discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18497935/584846

```
<accordion>
  <accordion-group ng-repeat="folder in folders | orderBy:'name' ">
    <accordion-heading>
      <span ng-click="select_folder(folder)">{{ folder.name }}</span>
    </accordion-heading>
    <accordion>
      <accordion-group ng-repeat="file in folder.files">
        <accordion-heading>
          <span ng-click="select_folder(folder)">{{ file.name }}</span>
        </accordion-heading>
        {{ file.info }}
      </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

An alternative is to `$watch` the value in the `is-open` attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15642577/584846